# php foreach inside variables

Tags: php, foreach

Im trying to loop through the records for txt2, but if I put the *foreach* outside of txt2, I only get one set of records and that is the problem.
What would be an easy and clean way to get the records' output?

```
<?php
$batfile = fopen("CNC/$wrtID/$wrtID.bat", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");


$txt1 = "
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO **** Run NC-Generator WOODWOP 4.0 ****";
?>
<?php
$txt2 = "
foreach($queryRecords as $res)
 {
 $code = $res['code'];
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-el.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-er.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-tb.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-dc.mpr
 }
";
 ?>
<?php
$txt3 ="
@ECHO **** Done ****
";
fwrite($batfile, $txt1);
fwrite($batfile, $txt2);
fwrite($batfile, $txt3);
fclose($batfile);
?>
```

Comment: you're putting php into a bat file?

Comment: im creating a bat file for a cnc machine

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the `foreach` inside of the string, and just concatenate with `.=`:

```
$txt2 = "";
foreach($queryRecords as $res)
{
$code = $res['code'];
$txt2 .= "
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-el.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-er.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-tb.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-dc.mpr";
}
```

If you don't need them separated, just concatenate them all into one `$txt`:

```
$txt = "
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO **** Run NC-Generator WOODWOP 4.0 ****";

foreach($queryRecords as $res)
{
$code = $res['code'];
$txt .= "
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-el.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-er.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-tb.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-$code-dc.mpr";
}
$txt .= "
@ECHO **** Done ****
";
fwrite($batfile, $txt);
```

Comment: then concatenate the 3 txt blocks and just write once for bonus points.

Comment: Nice i originally had it in one txt but couldnt figure out how to only run a loop on the files. Much cleaner looking!!